# How to delete a portion of an element's box model?

Tags: html, css

**Question:**

How can I delete a portion of the circle element's box model whose half portion is clipped so that it will create a half circle?

If deleting a portion of the box model is possible, please let me know and I will really appreciate it because I will be able to create complex shapes.

**Attempt:**

What I did is create a square `div`, add `border-radius: 100%` to round the corners, use `clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)` to control the polygon points the `div`, and use `aspect-ratio: 1/1` to prevent it from stretching. However, `clip-path` property only hides that portion of the `div` instead of also removing the box model of it.

**Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
.half_circle {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

Comment: If you specify something to have a height of  `100px` it will have that height. Anything else is nonsensical

Comment: it seems your are over-complicating a simple task. If you want a semi circle do :`aspect-ratio:2; clip-path:circle(farthest-side at top)` then define any height (or width you want)

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element.

```css
.half-circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  position: relative;
}
.half-circle::before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

Of course, in this case you could add `overflow: hidden` to `.half-circle` and then you don’t need the `clip-path`.

```css
.half-circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.half-circle::before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```